# Где можно почитать про создание нескольких NPC для простенькой игры на СИ?

Tags: c, искусственный-интеллект

Всем привет. В вузе задание сделать моделирование автомобильного трафика на СИ с использованием gl\GLUT. И вот возник вопрос, как добавлять несколько объектов со своей логикой? Т.е. машины создаются на карте с определённым промежутком и у каждой машины своя скорость. Машины должны учитывать ситуации когда можно производить обгон, а когда нельзя. Вот и встал вопрос, где можно почитать, как реализовать создание нескольких движущихся объектов на карте, у каждого из которых есть прописанная логика действий.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ну. Нужен класс/структура, описывающий одну машину, и вектор/список этих структур. Раз в кадр нужно проходить по списку и обновлять позицию каждой машинки (тут же принимать решение, обгонять или нет, и т.п.).